# Need help in solving $\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi }{ 2 } } \int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ { e }^{ sin(y) } } { sin(x)dydx }$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have tried to solve $\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  } \int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ { e }^{ sin(y) } } { sin(x)dydx }$ . I have solved it by using mathematica to evaluate $\int { { e }^{ sin(x) }dx } $ but it is turning tedious so hoping to get some insight into solve it in a better way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Changing the order of integration you get
$$\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  } \int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ { e }^{ \sin(y) } } { \sin(x)dydx }=\int _{ 0 }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  } \int _{ y }^{ \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } }{ { e }^{ \sin(y) } } { \sin(x)dxdy }$$
which is easy to integrate.

Comment: what is the principle behind it?

Comment: I got the expected answer e-1, but I am still not able to spot the rationale behind the suggestion?

Comment: @SHOURIEMRSS Whenever when you need to integrate a double integral $$\int \int f(x,y) dy dx$$ and your function is hard/impossible to integrate with respect to $y$ but easy to integrate with respect to $x$ it is natural to change the order of integration.... Start with the easy step, and see what you get, maybe the second integral is also easy....... This is a pretty standard exercise of order of integration.